# How to pass an action to task factory with weak reference to target

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, weak-references

Edit: I updated my code. Would this achieve what i am aiming for?

I have a working set of methods for async calling of methods but i have a specific problem with the references i pass in via a lambda. Specifically i have a (child) window that starts an operation and registers a callback. As you might expect, even when i close this window it still gets invoked.

What i want to do is pass in a kind of "weak reference" or construct a weak reference out of the incoming action.

Thhis is the way i build my Action (example code):

```
static Action CreateNewAction(Action call, Action<SomeArg> callback, 
    Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    return delegate {
        try
        {
            call();

            var target = callback.Target
            if(target != null)
                dispatcher.Invoke(callback, new SomeArg());
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle the ex in some way..
        }
    };
}
```

And this is how the task factory calls it:

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateNewAction(call, callback, dispatcher))
```

And this is how I would call it (the call just basses both the action and the callback through to the task factory as seen above):

```
WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(myTarget);
StartMyTaskAsync(someAction, ((MyTargetClass)wr.Target).SomeCompletedFunc);
```

Comment: And what exactly happens when you invoke that action on a closed window?

Comment: @svick hm well i am just building it so not much happening right now, but it returns data, and that could probably be set on a datacontext or something i guess.

Comment: So, why is it a problem when that happens?

Comment: @svick So, to shortcut this, do you propose to just ignore this specific case? I was worried because the child window would net get disposed this way.

Comment: `Window` is not `IDisposable`, so it can't be disposed. If you mean that it won't be garbage collected right away, then that's true. But it seems to me that's not an issue here, because the callback will eventually execute, and the window might be collected after that.

Comment: @svick You are right, thanks for pointing this out! However i want to be able to execute it on any target (not only windows) and be sure that the callback wont get fired of the target has been disposed or gc'ed. What i am testing now is checking for the target to be null before executing the callback. Also i build the callback like this: Do(action, (refer.Target as MyTargetClass).OnActionCompleted) where the second part is my callback. "refer" would be a new WeakReference(myTarget)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line:

```
StartMyTaskAsync(someAction, ((MyTargetClass)wr.Target).SomeCompletedFunc);
```

Specifically, this part:

```
((MyTargetClass)wr.Target).SomeCompletedFunc
```

You are materializing the target of the [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) to get the method that is referenced by the lambda/delegate long before you want to actually check whether or not the `WeakReference` has let go of the [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.target.aspx).

What you really want to do is pass a wrapper for your delegate, something like this (you didn't show the signature of `SomeCompletedFunc` so I don't know exactly what the call will be like, I'm assuming it's a parameterless void method for the purposes of this question):

```
StartMyTaskAsync(someAction, () => {
    // Check the weak reference.  If null, return.
    var target = wr.Target as MyTargetClass;

    // If null, return.
    if (target == null) return;

    // If not null, call.
    target.SomeCompletedFunc();
});
```

This way, you check the `Target` of the `WeakReference` *at the time you want to make the method call*, and not when you assign the callback.